Lyapunov stability lemma for retarded functional differential equations (FDEs) with infinite delay with bounded perturbations
I've recently been studying functional differential equations and want to know if there is any reference for stability analysis on FDEs with infinite delay and bounded perturbation. That is,
$\dot{\boldsymbol{x}}=\boldsymbol{f}(\boldsymbol{x}_t)+\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}, t\geq0$
with $\boldsymbol{x}_t(s)=\boldsymbol{x}(t+s)$ and $s \in (-\infty, 0]$.
For ODEs, there are many Lyapunov stability theorems about global asymptotical stability of the origin and the boundness of the state in the presence of the bounded perturbation (e.g. Lemma 4.16 and Lemma 9.3, Nonlinear Systems by Khalil). Is there any reference for those kinds of stability analysis on FDEs?

Is there a typo in your question? Namely it currently states: "... with infinite delay..."

No, it isn't a typo. $s \in (-\infty, 0]$ I think they are highly related to fractional calculus. I added this in the question

@Yun But that is still not an infinite delay. In fact, $s\in (-\infty, 0]$ denotes precisely that $s$ cannot be infinite. For time delay systems there are extensions of Lyapunov theorems, mainly the Krasovskii method and the Razumikhin method. You can take a look at the following reference as a starting point: Fridman, E. (2014). Tutorial on Lyapunov-based methods for time-delay systems. European Journal of Control, 20(6), 271-283.
